# Concatenate in actionscript not showing symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, concatenation

I have this flash program which is supposed to calculate the tip of a bill depending on the rating that you give it. In my Tip Percentage box I tried to have it concatenated to show the corresponding value + a percent symbol but the percent symbol is not getting displayed; only the value is there. Below is the code

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var tipTotal:Number = 0;
var split:Number = 0;
var tipPercent:Number = 0;
var bill:Number = 0;
var eachShare: Number = 0;

oneStar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, percentPopUp);
twoStar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, percentPopUp);
threeStar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, percentPopUp);
tipAmount_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculateTip);
share_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, calculateShare);

function percentPopUp(event:MouseEvent):void /*Tip percentage textbox will be filled with a percentage when a star is clicked on*/
{
    tipPercent = 0;
    if(event.target.name == "oneStar")
    {
        tipPercent = 5;
    }
    if (event.target.name == "twoStar")
    {
        tipPercent = 10;
    }
    if (event.target.name == "threeStar")
    {
        tipPercent = 20;
    }
    tipPercentage.text = tipPercent + "%";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your embedding. It could be that you forgot to embed "%" for that font in your FLA.